# Replace custom menu with Oracle Forms 11g default menu

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

In my main form window, I have the following menu bar which is used for traversing. Its inherited from .mmb file.

[image: Menu image 1]

Now, when I select any form on the menu, lets suppose I selected the highlighted "Purchase Order", then I don't want the same menu to be shown. I want the Oracle Form 11g's default menu to be shown instead, picture added below for reference.

[image: Menu bar 2]

I changed form's property of Inherit menu to No and the menu from image 1 isn't shown in "Purchase Order" but I still am not getting the default&smartbar menu.

How can I achieve that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out a way how to disable .mmx menu and enable DEFAULT&SMARTBAR menu when I go to another form through the menu.

From the first screenshot above, the on-click-trigger had the following code

```
call_form(:global.path||'pc');
```

I replaced it with

```
call_form(:global.path||'pc',hide,do_replace);
```

So the addition of

> ,hide,do_replace

worked.

Side note: Also, make sure **Inherit Menu** property of Window property is **"YES"** and **Menu Module** of form property is set to **"DEFAULT&SMARTBAR"**

Comment: I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

I think in the properties window from the form you got the property "menu module"

If you make a new form it gets the default: DEFAULT&SMARTBAR

So I think it is now filled with your mmb filename.

Comment: When I run/compile the form separately, I can see the DEFAULT&SMARTBAR menu but when I go through the menu page [image 1 in the main post], I don't see any menu bar attached.

I am guessing we have to replace the menu here.